# ggplot2-How do I use conditional colours in heat map

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, heatmap

I am looking for a way to make a plot like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR8WA.png)

And this is my R code to plot this heatmap. However, it does not work.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
pathway <- c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c")
value <- runif(9)

jet.colors <-colorRampPalette(c("#FE2423", "#F56C76", "#FCBEC3","#FEE4E6","#FFFFFF"))
nbcol <- 50
color <- jet.colors(nbcol)


ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=pathway,fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = ifelse(value<0.2,color,"black"))
```

What I expect is that, for tiles with value less or equal than 0.2, the color gradually changes from red to white. And for tiles with value more than 0.2, the color is not gradient (pure black).

Comment: this? `scale_fill_gradient(low ="white", high ="red")`

Comment: Sorry for the previous ambiguous expression. I have updated the description of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by setting the values for the gradient to `values=c(0, 0.2)`, the colors to red and white an the `na.value="black"`. To make the example a bit more interesting I added some additional data. (;

```r
# Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

data <- data.frame(x = rep(1:100, each = 100), pathway = rep(1:100, 100), value = runif(100 * 100))

ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=pathway,fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(breaks = seq(0, 1, .2), values = c(0, 0.2), colors = c("#FE2423", "#FFFFFF"), na.value = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!  That is what I expect. :)